# how do you disable Intel KVM user consent requirement?

Tags: remote-desktop, amt, intel

I'm trying to setup Intel vPro AMT KVM (Remote Desktop). I enabled AMT using the Intel SCS AMT Wizard. I'm now trying to use MCTME (shown in screenshot) to remotely connect to the computer. It works, but I need someone to read off an access code to me. This is what I assume to be "local user consent". When I try to disable it I get the error shown in the screenshot.

How do I use Intel vPro AMT KVM without needing someone to be at the other end?

EDIT: it seems the system is in "Client Control Mode", so that's why I can't change the setting. Any ideas on how I would change that?

Glossary

- Intel AMT: Active Management Technology. Hardware based remote control and management by Intel
- KVM: Keyboard Video Mouse
- [Intel SCS](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/software/setup-configuration-software.html): Setup and Configuration Software by Intel. Used to configure Intel AMT
- [MCTME](http://opentools.homeip.net/open-manageability): Manageability Commander Tool Mesh Edition

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

during AMT configuration, make sure to check "Display advanced settings" and choose "User consent not required"

[image]

Comment: You cannot disable User Consent in "Client Control Mode". You have to setup Intel AMT into "Admin Mode". Only then you can set it as "not required".